# mapa color por datos numericos

Tags: rstudio

¿como hacer que coloree el mapa por CCAA por datos numericos, por ejemplo Madrid vende 50000 pollos, C.Valenciana 1000, Cataluna 38000? Madrid al tener mayor cantidad estaría en rojo oscuro, Cataluña más claro y CValencia un rojo más palido. Como lo puedo hacer con Rstudio?

Comment: Hola @ANA bienvenidx a la comunidad, parece que tu pregunta se encuntra un poco floja, recuerda siempre ofrecer un buen contexto, con material de apoyo, código y que esté acompañada con tu mejor habilidad de redacción, te invito a leer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que te nutras sobre como usar stack a tu favor, de lo contrario podría afectar tu reputación en el futuro, no te desanimes, te invito a editar tu pregunta, un saludo.

Comment: Bienvenida ANA, tu pregunta es muy ampla, es más para un tutorial más que para una pregunta, hay muchos ejemplos en la red, este: https://pmoracho.github.io/blog/2017/05/11/Graficos-con-mapas-en-R/, seguramente no es es mejor pero es el que más a mano tengo. Saludos.